# How to find all triplets of nodes (connected components of size 3) from a tsv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx

From the matrix given below, i have to make a network and find all connected components of size 3.
The dataset i use is:

```
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Can anybody help?
And the expected connected connected triplets will be:-

```
1   2   3
1   3   4
2   1   3
3   1   4
```

My code:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

adj = []
infile="2_mutual_info_adjacency.tsv"
df=pd.read_csv(infile,delimiter="\t",header=None)
arr=np.array(df.iloc[0:10,:])
arr1=np.array(df.iloc[:,0:10])

for i in range(arr):
  for j in range(arr1):
    if (i,j)==1:
      for k in range(j+1,arr1):
        if (i,k)==1:
          adj.append(i,j,k)
      for l in range(i+1,arr):
        if(l,j)==1:
          adj.append(i,j,l)
```

A little bit of help will be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: can you also post the expected output?

Comment: See,the row index-2 and column index-6 has 1,also column index-6 and row index-5 also have 1..so the should come as 2,6,5 has a connection among themselves. And if possible,show it in a undirected graph.

Comment: @NicoHaase so far,i could get only the pair..but i have to find the triplet. And if possible show it in a undirected graph diagram.

My code:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import array as arr
import csv

infile="mutual_info_adjacency_test.tsv"
df=pd.read_csv(infile,delimiter="\t",header=None)
arr = np.array(df)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i][j] == 1:
           print(i,j)

Answer (score 2):

You can find all connected components using the function `connected_componets()`. Subsequently you can filter out the components, which consist of three nodes:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

adj_matrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(adj_matrix)

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)

# filter components of size 3
triplets = [c for c in nx.connected_components(G) if len(c) == 3]

triplets = set(chain.from_iterable(triplets))
color = ['lime' if n in triplets else 'pink' for n in  G.nodes()]

# jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color=color, node_size=1000)
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: How can i get the output in list form?

Comment: ` File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 611, in draw_networkx_edges
    if isinstance(alpha,number.Number):
NameError: name 'number' is not defined `

Comment: @NetranjitBorgohain `triplets` is the list that you need. You can remove the rest of code after `triplets` if you can’t draw the graph.

Comment: Its not showing anything. I wish i could have shown you the output. But i don't think i can send any pic in the comment.

Comment: `infile="discritaztion_transpose.tsv"
     df=pd.read_csv(infile,delimiter="\t",header=None)
     arr = np.array(df)
     print (arr)

     G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)


     triplets = [c for c in nx.connected_components(G) if len(c) == 3]
     print(triplets)`

That is my code

The output:
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
[]

Comment: Tried to read a .tsv file in the code you have given,but it is not being able to read the dataframe